# Name of an operation that transforms an ordered set into an ordered set of pairwise elements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there a name for an operation that takes in an ordered set:
$$X_{n} = (x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})$$ and spits out an ordered set of pairwise 2-tuples:
$$(X_{n},X_{n+1}) = \Big((x_{1},x_{2}),(x_{2},x_{3}),...,(x_{n},x_{n+1})\Big)$$

Comment: I would not use $(X_n,X_{n+1}) $ for this, as  that would usually denote an ordered pair. I doubt that the operation has a common name,but if you are using it often, feel free to give it one, e.g. $P(X_n, X_{n+1}).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an $n$-tuple $X=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ we let
$$X':=\bigl((x_1,x_2),(x_2,x_3),\ldots, (x_{n-1},x_n)\bigr)$$
be the corresponding $(n-1)$-tuple of successive pairs.